# Uploaded an aspx page, getting the "Sorry something went wrong. File Not Fount." message

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, asp.net

I copied and pasted an .aspx file to my siteassets folder.  When trying to access, I receive the "Sorry something went wrong.  File Not Found." message.  Is an .aspx page not a simple upload and click process?

Comment: please provide more information about your aspx file, how did you create it, in which environment you are trying to access it ?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I didn't create it.  We received it from another person.  They sent via email attachment, we downloaded it, and we click and drag into our site assets folder.  The file has all the ASP.Net delimiters in the code and it's referencing javascripts and css files on their server.  So I know we have to change that.  Both environments are 2013.  New to SharePoint, but now, I assume it's not a simple drag and drop.  Do we need to do something in Designer?

Comment: One other thing, we put it in the Site Pages Library.  Not sure if we need to put in a Document's library.

Comment: Ok, goto SharePoint designer, create new Aspx page and it will come with predefined lines, don't remove it. Copy the content for your page and put it into the newly created Aspx page and save it. Then open that page in browser

Comment: Ok, just place the content only from the old minus the delimiters and add it into the new page under the new page's delimiter?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your old Aspx page?? So that I can tell you from where you need to copy and paste it

Comment: You probably want to put it in your Site Pages or Wiki Pages library instead of Site Assets.  Depending on the privileges of the user account that is uploading the file and the user(s) attempting to browse to the page, you may need to explicitly publish a major version and review content Approval before it can be seen by others.

Comment: @willman - A former co-worker also stated that I should try to put it in the /_Layout/ folder in Designer.  Do you think that's a possible solution?

Comment: You can't access `/_layouts/` from Designer, you can only access it from the server.  If you are using SharePoint Online then you have no access to the `/_layouts/` folder.  If you have on prem, you can remote into the server and deploy manually, but that is generally risky if you are not using a fully packaged custom solution.